# How to extract with selenium and parse table data into DataFrame Pandas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, selenium-webdriver

I have a script which extracts all odds of the table. But the result is in a array.

Here is the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-fc-noah-fc-van-rid1159745.html')

odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "btn btn-default btn-xs btncote")]')))]

odds = [float(i) for i in odds]
odds = np.array(odds)
print(odds, '\n')
        
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Here is the output:

```
[1.68 3.2  3.95 1.65 3.25 4.   1.62 3.2  4.   1.65 3.1  3.8  1.58 3.2
 4.   1.58 3.2  3.95 1.57 3.15 3.95]
```

But in my case, I would like to have all odds in a DataFrame directly.
That's to say, extract with selenium and put data directly into a DataFrame with 3 columns (1, N, 2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need those big guns such as `numpy` or `selenium`. The entire table comes from a single end-point.

Here's a sample:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate


mapper = {"0": "Null", "1": "Fc Noah", "2": "Fc Van"}

end_point = "https://www.coteur.com/includes/ajax/getTendance.php?renc_id=1159745&defaultcote=1n2"
data = requests.get(end_point).json()

re_mapped = {
    datetime.fromtimestamp(int(date_point)): {
        mapper[key]: value for key, value in data_values.items()
    } for date_point, data_values in data.items()
}

df = pd.DataFrame(re_mapped)
print(tabulate(df))
df.to_csv("table.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

```
-------  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
Fc Noah  1.69  1.7   1.68  1.65  1.65  1.63  1.62  1.62  1.62  1.62  1.62  1.62  1.62
Null     3.17  3.17  3.18  3.17  3.18  3.19  3.19  3.2   3.19  3.19  3.19  3.19  3.18
Fc Van   3.84  3.83  3.85  3.86  3.87  3.91  3.94  3.96  3.94  3.95  3.96  3.95  3.95
-------  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
```

Or the `.csv`:

[image]

EDIT: Once you have the data, you can plot it.

```
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

mapper = {"0": "Null", "1": "Fc Noah", "2": "Fc Van"}
data = {'1613624300': {'1': '1.69', '0': '3.17', '2': '3.84'}, '1613625148': {'1': '1.70', '0': '3.17', '2': '3.83'}, '1613627005': {'1': '1.68', '0': '3.18', '2': '3.85'}, '1613633148': {'1': '1.65', '0': '3.17', '2': '3.86'}, '1613635106': {'1': '1.65', '0': '3.18', '2': '3.87'}, '1613638877': {'1': '1.63', '0': '3.19', '2': '3.91'}, '1613640164': {'1': '1.62', '0': '3.19', '2': '3.94'}, '1613642647': {'1': '1.62', '0': '3.20', '2': '3.96'}, '1613643799': {'1': '1.62', '0': '3.19', '2': '3.94'}, '1613644813': {'1': '1.62', '0': '3.19', '2': '3.95'}, '1613653368': {'1': '1.62', '0': '3.19', '2': '3.96'}, '1613666242': {'1': '1.62', '0': '3.19', '2': '3.95'}, '1613667102': {'1': '1.62', '0': '3.18', '2': '3.95'}}

re_mapped = {
    datetime.fromtimestamp(int(date_point)): {
        mapper[key]: float(value) for key, value in data_values.items()
    } for date_point, data_values in data.items()
}

df = pd.DataFrame(re_mapped)
df.T.plot(kind="line")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much your method is very fast.

Comment: I constat a difference between the data of the webage and the data scraped. Is it normal ?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: On the webage we have 7 rows for the table. In the dataframe there are 13 elements.

Comment: Plus the odds are not exactly the same

Comment: Well, if you plot it, it looks good. See the updated code.

Comment: ok I understand. your code extract the historical odds in the graph.

Comment: In my case I would like to extract the odds into the table

Comment: The odds into the table are current odds

Comment: The odds in the graph are past hour odds and I do not need it

Comment: But there's no other table there. Where are the current odds? The table show today's values.

Comment: I am speaking about the main table named "Cotes live". The values of this table are live odds whereas odds in the graph are old odds

Comment: In the main table you have the columns : 'Book' 'Fc Noah' 'nul' 'Fc Van' 'Retour' 'Hist' I want to extract odds of this main table